# Android MediaPlayer will not play different songs

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to use one MediaPlayer to play a number of songs in succession. The first song will play as needed, but afterwards, one particular song (the first song in alphabetic order) will play over and over again. I followed this: [Android Mediaplayer play different songs after eachother](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406110/android-mediaplayer-play-different-songs-after-eachother)

```
public void startPlayer(View view) {
    game = new Game();
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);

    // start first song
    Music firstSong = game.getNextSong();
    textView.setText(firstSong.getID());
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(view.getContext(), firstSong.getID());

    // make sure rest of songs play
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    goToNextSong();
                }
            });

    // actually start!
    mediaPlayer.start();
}

public void goToNextSong() {
    Music nextSong = game.getNextSong();
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);

    // if we still have music to play
    if (nextSong != null) {
        try {
            // set the new title
            textView.setText(nextSong.getID());
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.reset();

            // get the music file
             FileDescriptor fd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(
                    nextSong.getID()).getFileDescriptor();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fd);

            // play it!
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Even when I set fd to a particular song, it will still play the first song in alphabetical order. `nextSong.getID()` returns R.raw.somesong. The textview (which is set to the song ID) changes to the correct song. Help?

Comment: what is getNextSong();?

Comment: It returns a Music object and increments the song list counter. The Music object has getID() which returns R.raw.songtitle.

Comment: @olgash Have you tried the code in edit section of the question in the link you posted?

Comment: Yes, it's almost exactly what I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I haven't found a way to keep the same MediaPlayer and play different songs, so I just made a new one each time. It works!

```
public void startPlayer() {
    game = new Game();
    goToNextSong();
}

public void goToNextSong() {
    Music nextSong = game.getNextSong();
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);

    // if we still have music to play
    if (nextSong != null) {
        try {
            // set the new title
            textView.setText(nextSong.getID());

            // stop old music player
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            }

            // create new music player
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(textView.getContext(),
                    nextSong.getID());

            // make sure rest of songs play
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                            goToNextSong();
                        }
                    });

            // actually start!
            mediaPlayer.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        // we're done!
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
}
```